Swift 6 - Switch from @MainActor func to async function
How can I call in Swift 6 a normal async function from a MainActor function? I do not want to execute URLRequests on the MainThread
I want to switch from the Main Thread to an async Thread but I have no idea how to do it...
This code doesn't work and throws the following error: Sending 'self.service' risks causing data races
import SwiftUI

struct CustomView: View {
    private let viewModel: CustomViewModel = CustomViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Text("HELLO")
            .task {
                Task {
                    await viewModel.getDataFromBackend()
                }
            }
    }
}

@Observable
final class CustomViewModel {
    private let service: CustomService = DefaultCustomService()

    @MainActor func getDataFromBackend() async {
        // Updating UI on Main-Thread

        // This shouldn't run on the Main Thread!
        await service.provideBackendData()
    }
}


protocol CustomService {
    func provideBackendData() async
}

struct DefaultCustomService: CustomService {
    func provideBackendData() async {
        // Async Stuff which shouldn't run on Main-Thread
    }
}


A url request will run on an available thread. You simply need to await the operation. You don't need to anything to specifically dispatch it.

Is it? But if I follow the chain it means I have to mark everything as @MainActor - And this should mean it runs on the MainThread?

CustomService should also be an actor if you don't want it running in the callers context; if you want CustomService to run in an isolated context then you need to tell the compiler that

@Observable is for your model data. async funcs should go in a struct.

So the beauty of async-await is that you shouldn't care if your network requests are called on a background thread. If you really must execute something on a separate thread you'll want to use Task.detached (to avoid the parent context, which is most likely MainActor for SwiftUI's .task handler), but this is generally not recommended except for very specialised use cases

Now in a MVVM type situation you'd have your ViewModel call the provideBackendData and update some @Published property with the result. Which would have to be done on main if it's using SwiftUI bindings. But for this you can simply use await MainActor.run {} to propagate the values to the UI bindings at the last possible point in time.

Wow that is a good point! Thank you @Paulw11 - I will try it later to conform to the Actor protocol and see on which Thread it will run. - But it makes sense what you say!

You can just add
protocol CustomService: Sendable {

To remove the error.
In order to safely make something Sendable you should meet all of these official requirements

Value types
Reference types with no mutable storage
Reference types that internally manage access to their state
Functions and closures (by marking them with @Sendable)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sendable
Unofficially any reference types should also be marked final so the user cant create unsafe mutating children.
You can also use actor and globalActor to make something Sendable.

Currently your async func is an @Observable class which is for model data not for services, i.e. its designed to hold shared mutable state which is not usually something a service does. To fix your data races warning your async func can either be static (i.e. no risk of shared mutatble state) or in a sendable struct. To use async/await in SwiftUI with Swift 6 with a mockable service try something like this:
import SwiftUI

struct Result: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    @Entry var controller: IController = Controller()
}

protocol IController: Sendable {
    func fetchResults() async throws -> [Result]
}

struct Controller: IController {
    func fetchResults() async throws -> [Result] {
        [.init(title: "Result 1"), .init(title: "Result 2")]
    }
}

struct PreviewController: IController {
    func fetchResults() async throws -> [Result] {
        [.init(title: "Preview Result 1"), .init(title: "Preview Result 2")]
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.controller) var controller
    @State var results: [Result] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                ForEach(results) { result in
                    Text(result.title)
                }
            }
        }
        .task {
            do {
                results = try await controller.fetchResults()
            }
            catch {}
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
        .environment(\.controller, PreviewController())
}



This breaks practically every single principle of SOLID

This does not solve the issue., will cause the same data races mentioned by OP even if we correct all the typos and missing steps.

Thanks for you answer but this is actually the thing which confused me. You need to run fetchResults() on the MainThread because you are calling it from the View

With async/await the thread is decided based on where the func is declared not where it is called from. If you declare it in a struct that is not MainActor it will not be main thread.
